# Asp.net redirect from login to main page

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, iis-7.5

i have 2 pages on my webapp. Login.aspx and Main.aspx.

After a successful login username and password i redirect from login.aspx to Main.aspx as shown below in c#.
This works fine in visual studio 2010.
The problem is that when i deploy my website the value localhost does not make sense.

Can i determine the server name that the website is running on or should i somehow place the server redirect main page link in my web.config file?

thanks
Damo

```
string Redirectport = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_PORT"];
RedirectURL = "http://localhost:" + Redirectport + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ApplyAppPathModifier("~/Main.aspx");
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about

`RedirectURL = Page.ResolveUrl("~/Main.aspx")` ?

this is the "default" way to do it.

Comment: This is correct answer for the question, But I would not hard code  my login redirect page in code. Instead I will set RedirectURL = Page.ResolveUrl("~/"); And then set default document for the site in web.config file.  (This is assuming site has authentication required and redirects user to Login page if user is not authenticated).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the server variable SERVER_NAME

```
string serverName = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"]
RedirectURL = "http://" + serverName + ":" + Redirectport + 
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ApplyAppPathModifier("~/Main.aspx");
```

Comment: That will get the name of the server specified in the requested URL.  So `http://server1.com/something.aspx` would be redirected to `http://server1.com/Main.aspx` after that code runs.

Comment: hi, answer correct - can you add the ":" as shown here to your answer then i will mark yours as correct.                     string Redirectport = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_PORT"];
                    string serverName = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"];
                    RedirectURL = "http://" + serverName + ":" + Redirectport + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ApplyAppPathModifier("~/Main.aspx");

Comment: This answer works for the specific situation of the OP, but in most cases the URL won't point to the server's root. Instead it will be something like `http://server1.com/SiteA/Main.aspx`

Comment: thank you eric and danoloquio thanks for the heads up on that potential issue. regards damo

Comment: @daniloquio.  Agree.  I upvoted the accepted answer, but am leaving mine because it may be situationally valuable to someone.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to put the server name in the `web.config` file and load it in the `Global.asax` file under Application_Start event

in the `web.config` file:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Domain" value="yourdomain" />
</appSettings>
```

in `Global.asax` file:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SomeStaticGlobalClass.Domain = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Domain"];
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Comment: That's one more thing to configure (and maybe forget to configure) that can instead be taken from the requested URL.

Comment: And what if you gonna change your domain to a subdomain or anything else? dont forget that in IIS, you can configure multiple domains to application

Answer (score 0):

if you want navigate to some internal web page , you can use something like below

```
Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
```

you also can use it navigate to other server

```
Response.Redirect("https://www.google.com/");
```